Can you install a ceiling fan on this bracket?
I have a light fixture installed here and I am planning to replace it with a ceiling fan with light fixtures.


Can you?  Probably.  Should you?  Probably not.

On the bracket - no absolutely not. That bracket is only meant for a light fixture. A ceiling fan would be mounted directly to the box (after you remove the bracket), but there's insufficient info in your pic to tell if the box is good enough for a fan.

There is no telling from the picture if the box is fan rated or not.
You need to take of the bracket and examine the inside of the box for the notation of , " Fan rated'  or "Approved for fan"  Or something of that nature.
